# Getting a newline in the midst of a subset of an array when writing to a file

Tags: fortran

I have a Fortran routine that concatenates multiple files. Given input files:

**f1.txt**

```
1  1 2 3
2  1 2 3
3  1 2 3
```

**f2.txt**

```
1  4 5 6 7
2  4 5 6 7
3  4 5 6 7
```

**output**

```
1  1 2 3 4 5 6 7
2  1 2 3 4 5 6 7
3  1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

No biggie, quite simple. Should accept any number of files, row-concatenates them while ignoring the first column. Each files may differ in number of columns, but not rows. Columns contain numeric values, not just integers.

**Problem**

For some reason, when the number of columns differs, new lines sneak in at deterministic positions. Of what I can determine, it happens when "switching" to a file with fewer columns. It shouldn't happen (the newline), but it is. Why?

```
PROGRAM TEST
IMPLICIT NONE

character(255), dimension(2) :: fns
integer :: files, nlines, result
character(255) :: fnout
integer, dimension(2) :: ncols

! subroutine rowconcat(files, fns, fnout, nlines, ncols, result)

files=2
fns(1) = 'f2.txt'
fns(2) = 'f1.txt'
fnout = 'fres.txt'
nlines=3
ncols(1) = 2
ncols(2) = 4



CALL rowconcat(files, fns, fnout, nlines, ncols, result)  ! In rowconcat.f95

END

! Concatenates genotype matrices (from e.g. multiple chromosomes) into one.
! No row ID checking.
subroutine rowconcat(files, fns, fnout, nlines, ncols, result)
  implicit none

  integer, intent(in) :: files, nlines
  character(255), intent(in) :: fnout
  character(255), dimension(files), intent(in) :: fns
  integer, dimension(files), intent(in) :: ncols
  integer, intent(out) :: result

  integer :: i, j, id, stat
  integer, dimension(files) :: units
  real, dimension(:,:), allocatable :: row
  character(50) :: fmt0
  character(50), dimension(files) :: fmt
  character(4), dimension(files) :: advance

  allocate(row(files,maxval(ncols, 1)))
  !row(:) = 9 

  advance(:) = 'no'
  advance(files) = 'yes'

  print *, files, nlines
  print *, advance
  do i=1,files
    print *, trim(fns(i)), ncols(i)
  enddo
  !print *,nlines,ncols

  do i=1,files
    units(i) = 200 + i
    open(units(i), file=fns(i), status='OLD')
    write(fmt0, '(i5)') ncols(i)
    fmt(i)='('//trim(adjustl(fmt0))//'F5.2)'
  end do
  open(55, file=fnout, status='UNKNOWN')
  print *, fmt

  do j=1,nlines
    do i=1,files
      read(units(i), *, iostat=stat) id, row(i,1:ncols(i))
      if (stat /= 0) exit
      !print *, ncols(i), row(1:ncols(i)), 'Bla.'
      if (i == 1) write(55, '(i20)', advance='no') id
      write(55, fmt, advance=advance(i)) row(i,1:ncols(i))
    end do
    if (stat /= 0) exit
  end do

  deallocate(row)

  close(55)
  do i=1,files
    close(units(i))
  end do

  result=stat

end subroutine rowconcat
```

(The subroutine is part of an R-package, so there are some wrapper functions, but the code above reproduces the problem.)

**Result**

```
                   1 1.00 2.00 3.00 4.00 5.00 6.00
 7.00
                   2 1.00 2.00 3.00 4.00 5.00 6.00
 7.00
                   3 1.00 2.00 3.00 4.00 5.00 6.00
 7.00
```

No, it is not word-wrapped. A new-line has sneaked in before the last element. Why?

Swap the two files and the routine works as expected. But, it depends somehow on the order of number of columns.

Comment: I wonder how you even got this output... You have switched the first and second file in your code, you specify the wrong number of columns per file, you use the `fmt` array instead of a single format when writing to the file - in short: your code is a mess. Sorry. Please clean it up. Also if you know the rows and columns of each sub-matrix beforehand, why don't you simply fill a large array blockwise, and print it out in one go?

Comment: Ay, the error was not using the ``fmt`` array.

Answer (score 2):

As noted in a comment, your code does not reproduce your output.  Your initial settings are inconsistent with your input files.

```
files=2
fns(1) = 'f2.txt'
fns(2) = 'f1.txt'
fnout = 'fres.txt'
nlines=3
ncols(1) = 2
ncols(2) = 4
```

should be

```
files=2
fns(1) = 'f1.txt'
fns(2) = 'f2.txt'
fnout = 'fres.txt'
nlines=3
ncols(1) = 3
ncols(2) = 4
```

In your subroutine you had some messy code and a lot of logic to manage your reads and writes.  As @AlexanderVogt says, it makes more sense to read into an array and write it out at once.  I'll meet you halfway and instead do row-based IO in case memory constrains your ability to load all data into memory at once.  Consider this modified version of `rowconcat`:

```
subroutine rowconcat(files, fns, fnout, nlines, ncols, result)
  implicit none

  integer, intent(in) :: files, nlines
  character(255), intent(in) :: fnout
  character(255), dimension(files), intent(in) :: fns
  integer, dimension(files), intent(in) :: ncols
  integer, intent(out) :: result

  integer :: i, j, id, stat, total_columns, start_column
  integer, dimension(files) :: units
  real, dimension(:), allocatable :: row
  character(50) :: fmt
  character(8) :: str_cols

  total_columns = sum(ncols)
  allocate(row(total_columns))

  do i=1,files
    units(i) = 200 + i
    open(units(i), file=fns(i), status='OLD')
  end do
  open(55, file=fnout, status='UNKNOWN')
  write(str_cols,'(i8)') total_columns
  write(fmt,'(A)') '(I20,'//trim(adjustl(str_cols))//'F5.2)'

  do j=1,nlines
     start_column = 1
     do i=1,files
        read(units(i), *, iostat=stat) id, row(start_column:start_column+ncols(i)-1)
        start_column = start_column+ncols(i)
        if (stat /= 0) exit
     end do
     write(55, fmt, iostat=stat) id, row
     if (stat /= 0) exit
  end do

  deallocate(row)

  close(55)
  do i=1,files
    close(units(i))
  end do

  result=stat

end subroutine rowconcat
```

The primary changes to this are

- allocate an entire output row of elements in `row`
- use a single format `fmt` for all writes
- for each line

  - for each file: read elements from file into row at the proper position
  - output row
    This reduces the housekeeping logic to just making note of which column you are at to start filling in the next files row.

---

I didn't bother diagnosing why your code didn't work because at face value it produced gibberish.  It wasn't until I modified the subroutine into my version that I noted your input values were broken and at that point I wasn't in any mood to revert working code and start over trying to see what you were doing wrong.